# Making items in a custom list form "clickable"

Tags: 2010, content-type

I've got a display form for a list in Sharepoint 2010. I've added a second list which is related and added a section to my form using "Related Item View" in Sharepoint Designer.

Since the related item includes a date and a selection I have no need of the default "title" column which I have hidden and want to remove from the form too.

At the moment I have:

```
<ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
          <FieldRef Name="Date"/>
          <FieldRef Name="Action"/>
</ViewFields>
```

The problem is that it is the title which has the link (I guess as "linktitle" that makes sense) which allows the user to select/open/edit. Is there a way to make another column the "clickable" link, or do I have to write my own javascript to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify needed field in your conten type like this:

```
<Fields>
    <Field ID="xxxx" Type="xxxx"
        StaticName="xxxx"
        Name="xxx"
        DisplayName ="xxxx"
        Required="TRUE"
        LinkToItem="TRUE"
        LinkToItemAllowed="Required"
        ListItemMenu="TRUE"/>
</Fileds>
```

Comment: Thanks! The change I made was just to give:
 <FieldRef Name="Action" LinkToItem="True"/> and that seemed to work.

Comment: @DaveAlger Can you elaborate where do you put this code? I am a totally new to sharepoint and need to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I'm afraid this is long enough ago that my memory is a little fuzzy and I don't have access to the Sharepoint development tools any more. I'd suggest writing a new question and I'm sure some experts will be able to help.